# Python 2.7 Verify Directory Return False While I Not Use Something Not String Directly

Tags: python

Firstly, this is my first post on the website if i did any mistake during topic sorry about that.

My problem is I am currently trying to retrive home location of user with that way i am planning to git clone to that directory but I tried to many way to find out location of user home.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cd && pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = p.communicate()[0]

def getusername():
    username = subprocess.check_output(["echo $HOME"],shell=True)
    return username
```

and etc but when i get the value from them and use it like this

```
print os.access(result, os.F_OK) // returning false
```

I already check the value and try to type value as string to there for examp lets say that `/home/user/` is returning value, result is holding same value but return false but when i type `print os.access("/home/user", os.F_OK)`,  I am getting true but i didn't understand why i tried too many different way also i tried `os.path.exist` or `os.path.directory` and etc all them is working when i typed as manual. But  if i write  the variable name into there its not working

I almost spend night to find out it but with no luck i was not able to figure out. and also i trying to add some manual string to if i solve this problem next step is going to be like `os.access(result + "/Veil", os.F_OK)` but when I do like:

```
n  = result + "/Veil"
print n
```

Result is appearing something like:

```
/home/user
/Veil
```

Its showing them separate line I also think that maybe thats problem but even if a remove it still not working. If someone tell me whats the problem i will be soo happy from now thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your need is to find the user directory, just us [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) method like this :

```
os.path.expanduser("~")
>> /home/user
```

Comment: Finally , that worked. Thank you so much but the think i didnt understand it actually return my home and i set the result of it to variable and use it to verify file and its worked . But when i use                                              
        p = subprocess.Popen("cd && pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
       shell=True)
       result = p.communicate()[0]                                                                           or  def getusername():
    username = subprocess.check_output(["echo $HOME"],shell=True)
    return username  it return the same value too but didnt worked